# .htaccess 301 redirect including subpages based on referral

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https:\/\/([^.]+.)*?forum.[a-zA-Z_]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://visitorfromforum.org/ [R,L]
```

How to redirect all traffic [/ and all sub-pages] to http://visitorfromforum.org/?
Currenly this redirection works only with /, visitors from ****forum.org clicking on mysit.com/images/2013/09/03/index.html are still able to see my content.
Any ideas?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect all the current pages to `visitorfromforum.org` then remove your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` and use `$1` in redirected URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://.+?\.forum\..+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://visitorfromforum.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks pal, but I only want to redirect people coming from ****forum.org

Comment: Not working, I'm able to visit mysite.com by clicking on the link from ***.forum.org :( Thanks anyway pal :)

Comment: I suggest you state your requirement clearly. This answer will redirect to `http://visitorfromforum.org/` if referrer is from `someforum.org`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: E.g there are 3 links pointing to mysite.com on someforum.org: 1) mysite.com 2) mysite.com/archive/2013/09/09/ 3) mysite.com/category/page-with-some-info/. I want to redirect all traffic coming from this forum to http://visitorfromforum.org/. Using my current code I can redirect visitor clicking on mysite.com/ from someforum.org but people clicking on mysite.com/sub-pages/ from someforum.org are still able to visit my site :)

Comment: Traffic coming from someforum.org from cliks on mysite.com are redirected to visitorfromforum.org. Traffic coming from someforum.org on clicks on mysite.com/archive/2013/09/09/ are not :(

Comment: I have made another edit. Make sure to test in a different browser.